# Alpha numeric primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following code in ASP.NET MVC.

I would like that my program could save auto-incremented alpha numberic primary key.

First 2 alphabets must be 'ST' and the next 4 should be digits which has to be auto-incremental. Is there any way I could handle this task through data annotation?

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: split you alphanumeric key and then just increment the int part and concatenate it again

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using **SQL Server** as your database engine (isn't clear from your question), then the only viable solution is to use

- a `StudentIDRaw INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column `StudentID` to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student
(
    StudentIDRaw INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    StudentID AS 'ST' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(StudentIDRaw AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED,
     .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Student` table without specifying values for `StudentIDRaw` or `StudentID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Student(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `StudentIDRaw` value, and `StudentID` will contain values like `ST0001`, `ST0002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates. And it does so **in the database** - so no matter whether you're looking at your data with your own application, or with Mgmt Studio - you **see** that alphanumeric `StudentID` just fine

Answer (score 0):

You would have to generate the alphanumeric key in your code your self for every record you enter in your database. For that first you would have to get the `max Id` from your database, using this id you can generate your alphanumeric key by doing something like this:

```
public string getAlphaNumericKey()
{
    int number = maxidfromDB();

    if(number > 0)
    {
        return "ST"+ number.ToString("0000"); 
    } 
    else
    {
        return "ST0001";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I tried it and it doesn't Turn out to be the Best Solution. Its because Lets say if I add a Record and database Generated its ID as _12_ and VarcharID as _ST0012_.
Now if I delete this Record (ID = 12) and then try to Add Another record afterwards. the **maxidfromdb()** function Will return _11_. The system will Generate the next Record ID as _13_ and its VarcharID is going to be **ST0012** which is conflicting the Orignal Purpose of Generating the VarcharID

Answer (score 0):

You could let the database handle the auto increment by using an `Identity` declaration on the `Id` column.

In your application you can concat that incremented Id number with a qualifier to achieve what you need.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Key { get { return KeyQualifier + Id.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'); } }
    public string KeyQualifier { get; set; } = "ST";
    public int Id { get; set; } //The Identity in the database
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Key` property will return the alphanumeric that you desire.